# Purity of Phobos reduce

Tags: function, d, reduce, purely-functional

Why isn't `std.algorithm.reduce` in Phobos pure? Is it an unfixed Issue or is there a reason why it can't be?

Has this something todo with the question:
*"What does a pure function look like"*
Andrei asked in the final lecture at DConf 2013?

See: http://forum.dlang.orgthread/20120306224101.GA30389@quickfur.ath.cx

I want the function `sparseness` in the following code to be pure. I guess I could always replace `reduce` with a `foreach` loop for now right?

```
import std.algorithm: reduce, min, max;
import std.typetuple: templateAnd;
import std.traits: isArray, Unqual;
import std.range: ElementType, isInputRange, isBidirectionalRange, isFloatingPoint;

//** Returns: true if $(D a) is set to the default value of its type. */
bool defaulted(T)(T x) @safe pure nothrow { return x == T.init; }
alias defaulted untouched;

/** Returns: Number of Default-Initialized (Zero) Elements in $(D range). */
size_t sparseness(T)(in T x, int recurseDepth = -1) @trusted /* pure nothrow */ {
    import std.traits: isStaticArray;
    static if (isStaticArray!T ||
               isInputRange!T) {
        import std.range: empty;
        immutable isEmpty = x.empty;
        if (isEmpty || recurseDepth == 0) {
            return isEmpty;
        } else {
            const nextDepth = (recurseDepth == -1 ?
                               recurseDepth :
                               recurseDepth - 1);
            static if (isStaticArray!T) { // TODO: We can't algorithms be applied to static arrays?
                typeof(return) ret;
                foreach (ref elt; x) { ret += elt.sparseness(nextDepth); }
                return ret;
            } else {
                import std.algorithm: map, reduce;
                return reduce!"a+b"(x.map!(a => a.sparseness(nextDepth)));
            }
        }
    } else static if (isFloatingPoint!T) {
        return x == 0; // explicit zero because T.init is nan here
    } else {
        return x.defaulted;
    }
}
unittest {
    assert(1.sparseness == 0);
    assert(0.sparseness == 1);
    assert(0.0.sparseness == 1);
    assert(0.1.sparseness == 0);
    assert(0.0f.sparseness == 1);
    assert(0.1f.sparseness == 0);
    assert("".sparseness == 1);
    assert(null.sparseness == 1);
    immutable ubyte[3]    x3   = [1, 2, 3];    assert(x3[].sparseness == 0);
    immutable float[3]    f3   = [1, 2, 3];    assert(f3[].sparseness == 0);
    immutable ubyte[2][2] x22  = [0, 1, 0, 1]; assert(x22[].sparseness == 2);
    immutable ubyte[2][2] x22z = [0, 0, 0, 0]; assert(x22z[].sparseness == 4);
}
```

**Update:**

I decided on instead using `isIterable` and `foreach` instead of the above, as this works just aswell for me right now and makes things `@safe pure nothrow`. I see no need right now to use higher order functions to solve this problem. I also found Davids Simchas' upcoming `std.rational` very natural to use here:

```
import rational: Rational;

/** Returns: Number of Default-Initialized (Zero) Elements in $(D x) at
    recursion depth $(D depth).
*/
Rational!ulong sparseness(T)(in T x, int depth = -1) @safe pure nothrow {
    alias R = typeof(return); // rational shorthand
    static if (isIterable!T) {
        import std.range: empty;
        immutable isEmpty = x.empty;
        if (isEmpty || depth == 0) {
            return R(isEmpty, 1);
        } else {
            immutable nextDepth = (depth == -1 ? depth : depth - 1);
            ulong nums, denoms;
            foreach (ref elt; x) {
                auto sub = elt.sparseness(nextDepth);
                nums += sub.numerator;
                denoms += sub.denominator;
            }
            return R(nums, denoms);
        }
    } else static if (isFloatingPoint!T) {
        return R(x == 0, 1); // explicit zero because T.init is nan here
    } else {
        return R(x.defaulted, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be due to the unaryFunc helper not being pure. What happens if you change your "a+b" to instead refer to a separate function you write that is explicitly marked pure? so like `pure int add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }` at module scope then `reduce!add(...)`. I know that's a bit of an extra hassle, but just want to see what happens. (I'd check myself but my cable is still out at home so can't remote connect and I'm on my device without dev tools!)

Answer (score 4):

If you change `nextDepth` to `immutable` rather than `const` then `sparseness` will be `pure`.

I believe this is a bug, it may be to do with the closure being passed to `reduce` capturing `nextDepth`, and for some reason thinking it may be mutable because it is `const`. Values *declared* as `const` are however identical to those declared as `immutable` -- the difference only manifests itself with indirections -- so I believe it is an error.

You may want to file a minimal repro case as a bug.

(it cannot be `nothrow` however, because `reduce` can, in fact, throw)